# Apache returns default page instead my content

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, apache-2.4, high-load, bug

My web site works perfect, but sometimes apache returns default html page:

```
It works!
This is the default web page for this server.
The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.
```

No configs and other settings at this time have not changed. I looked through the logs and noticed that at this moment there was a lot of simultaneous requests per second.

I have a question. Can Apache under heavy load to display the above page, not the site's content?

Or what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Apache HTTP Server would not serve different content based on load). It seems like some misconfiguration on your `VirtualHost`, try [VirtualHost Examples - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.2](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html), pay extra attention to `ServerName` and make sure that set correctly.

Comment: VirtualHost and ServerName are correct

Comment: take a look into logs, see what's going on there...

Comment: Apache error log empty, nothing strange in access log...

Answer (score 0):

Have you set up your VirtualHosts config to handle aliases of your main website address?

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

If www isn't an Alias, and someone uses www (or vice versa, doesn't) they will get the default Apache page.